# Open Custom Webpart from "Add new item" Click from sharepoint list using c#

Tags: list, office-365, custom-list, office-365-developer

[image]

I want to open Custom WebPart on click of "add new item" link (as shown in above image) in SharePoint list Programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit the default new form.

1. Go to list ribbon and click on **Form Web Parts**. From drop down
   click on **Default New Form**.

[image]

2. This will open New form in **Edit** mode.
   [image]
3. Add your custom webpart on the form and **hide** the original webpart.

Comment: Code Throw Possible!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: This may help http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/163470/configure-custom-forms-for-new-and-edit-using-csom I don't work on O365 so not sure whether this link will help you or not.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by adding a custom action that can be to the Style Library. You would need to design your custom form programmatically in this custom action - JavaScript file and associate to this list.